# JavaFX: How to set priority on a focusProperty change listener

Tags: java, events, javafx, focus

My scenario: I have a TextField and a ListView. As the user types text into the text field, a list of building material suggestions come up (loaded from database).

Desired functionality: I want the user to be able to click on a material suggestion and have it automatically fill the TextField with the full name of the material. However, if the user stops focusing the TextField (and clicks anywhere else), and the material doesn't exist in the DB, it should show a dialog box asking them to add the material to the database.

Current functionality: When the user clicks off the TextField the dialog box pops up all fine. However, when the user clicks on one of the suggestions in the ListView, the focusProperty change event of the TextField is called BEFORE the selectedItemProperty change event of the ListView. Therefore, the user gets a pop-up asking them to add a material to the DB when in fact they wanted to simply select one of the suggestions in the ListView.

My question is, is there any way for me to set the priority of the focus change event, so that select item event is called before a "valid material" check is made by the focus event? If not, how else may I tackle this issue?

My initialize method:

```
@FXML
public void initialize() { 
    // Search list
    searchList.getItems().addAll(StockedMaterial.getStockedMaterials());
    searchList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue != null) {
            setStockedMaterial(newValue);
        }
    });

    nameField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue) commit();
    });

    updateAll();

    //This needs to be after the above, as setText will trigger it 
    nameField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> searchMaterials(oldVal, newVal));
}
```

Commit method which checks for a valid material, and adds it if not valid:

```
@FXML
public void commit() {
    requiredMaterial.setQuantityRequired(quantityField.getDouble());

    StockedMaterial stockedMaterial = StockedMaterial.getStockedMaterialByName(nameField.getText());

    if (stockedMaterial == null && (stage == null || !stage.isShowing())) {
        if (!nameField.getText().equals("")) {
            stage = StageUtil.createDialogStage(Resources.getResource("materials.add"));
            stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                delete();
            });

            VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
            vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            SceneUtil.changeScene(stage, vbox);

            Label infoLabel = new Label(Resources.getResource("quotes.materialCreated", nameField.getText()));
            vbox.getChildren().add(infoLabel);

            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            grid.setHgap(5);
            grid.setVgap(5);
            grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            vbox.getChildren().add(grid);

            Label quantityLabel = new Label(Resources.getResource("materials.quantityInStock"));
            DoubleTextField quantity = new DoubleTextField();
            grid.addRow(0, quantityLabel, quantity);

            Label quantityTypeLabel = new Label(Resources.getResource("materials.quantityType"));
            ComboBox<QuantityType> combo = new ComboBox<QuantityType>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(QuantityType.values()));
            grid.addRow(1, quantityTypeLabel, combo);

            combo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

            Button add = new Button(Resources.getResource("materials.add"));
            add.setOnAction(e -> {
                StockedMaterial newMaterial = new StockedMaterial();
                newMaterial.setNewModel(true);
                newMaterial.setName(nameField.getText());
                newMaterial.setQuantityInStock(quantity.getDouble());
                newMaterial.setQuantityTypeId(combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getId());
                newMaterial.save();

                requiredMaterial.setStockedMaterial(newMaterial);
                updateAll();
                SceneUtil.closeScene(add);
            });

            vbox.getChildren().add(add);
            stage.sizeToScene();
        } else {
            delete();
        }
    } else {
        setStockedMaterial(stockedMaterial);
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

When I type "br" and attempt to click Brick, I get the dialog box below, which should only happen if I was to click on anything OTHER than the Brick item in the ListView.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it work to just check the `ListView` is not focused in the focus handler? i.e. `if ( ! newValue && ! searchList.isFocused() ) commit();`

Comment: @James_D Was my exact thoughts, already tried it. It doesn't work, because the search list is not actually focused at the time when the TextField is unfocused - only AFTER its focus event has returned.